# dropdownlist in view with bool values

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

In model I have property

```
public UserType UserType { get; set; }

 public enum UserType
    {
        first,
        second
    }

@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.UserType ,"All",new { @class = "form-control"})
```

How I can send to controller value which mean all usertype: first or second
in DropDownList in view i have three fields: first, second, all

All means first or second. And I can't edit enum UserType

Comment: Unclear what your expecting. Your binding to an enum which has only 2 possible values `first` or `second` which you say you cannot change. If you select the `All` option, your model will be invalid.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - I dint quite get it either but made an attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@Html.EnumDropDownListFor()`

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.UserType ,"All",new { @class = "form-control"})
```

Change your property to accept nullable values:

```
public UserType? UserType {get;set}
```

Within your `Action`, you can then detect if nothing/all was supplied:

```
if (myModel.UserType == null)
    // All was selected.
```

Although, you should add the All item to your enum, otherwise how would you bind the value all to your model?

```
[Required]
public UserType? UserType {get;set}

public enum UserType
{
    first,
    second,
    all
}
```

Then you can use:

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.UserType,"Please Select", new { @class = "form-control"})
```

Comment: If user choose all it means i need show first and second type of user

Comment: but isnt this what you said in your question? "How I can display in DropDownList in view three fields: first, second, all?"

Comment: @Ric, Unfortunately this will not work correctly. The 2nd parameter of `EnumDropDownListFor` adds `<option value="">All</option>` which means your now rendering 2 options with `"All"`. It would need to be something like `@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.UserType ,"Please select" ...)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke isn't that what I've suggested in the second usage? the first example adds "All" without modifying the enum, second adds all to the enum and adds the "please select"

Comment: The second one is fine :) I was referring to the 1st one which I assumed you meant to also use with the modified enum (because otherwise it would be identical to the code in OP's question)

Comment: @StephenMuecke ah - the op edited the question to include the syntax which I already had, the second was for the modified enum :D

Comment: @Ric First solution before editing your answer is correct for me. But I can another problem. Sometimes class "input-validation-error" add to this dropdown in markup

Comment: Now it makes sense - hadn't noticed OP had edited it :)

Comment: @Kevin, In the first example, if you select `All` the model will be invalid because its value is `null`. You need to change the property to be nullable `public UserType? UserType {get;set}` without the `[Required]` attribute. Then in the POST method, if `UserType = null` you know the user selected `"All"`

Comment: Yes, making it nullable is the important part if you can't change the enum. if "all" is selected, the value will be null as @StephenMuecke points out. The required attribute will invalidate your model as this implies a value has to be present/supplied

Comment: You are right. I make nullable property. And change code, because, when property was unnullable dropdown return 0, when user choose all. Thanks

Comment: Glad we could help @Kevin